# How to create reset button in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Please help me in finding a solution:

I have created a button in tableau which reset all the filters and will select all the values in filters and displays in the dashboard.

But my requirement is if I click the button it should un-select all the filters and should show the blank dashboard.

Is there any way this can be achieved in Tableau 10.5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful to see the button that you created so others can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you are using Tableau Server, you can use the JavaScript API to get the behavior you need - could make your button with HTML/CSS and then have the button trigger a JavaScript function that resets your filters